# Convert PWideChar to String. Should I use WideCharToString?

Tags: string, delphi, widechar

I am using Delphi XE3.

In the following codes:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: PWideChar;
  B: string;
  C: string;
begin
  A := '123';

  B := A;
  C := WideCharToString(A);
end;
```

It seems that both direct assignment and WideCharToString can convert PWideChar to string. In such a case, why anyone will use WideCharToString to do the conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both operations call `_UStrFromPWChar` routine from `system.pas`, so work similarly.

Somebody might prefer explicit function call rather than implicit conversion to be sure what really happens.

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi 2009 and later, `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString`. However, `WideCharToString()` long predates `UnicodeString`, dating back all the way to at least Delphi 5 (maybe even earlier) when `String` was an alias for `AnsiString` instead.

Why a function was ever needed, I do not know. <sup>1</sup> At least as far back as Delphi 5, a `PWideChar` could be assigned directly to an `AnsiString`, converting the 16bit UCS-2/UTF-16 data into 8bit ANSI data (via the RTL's `_LStrFromPWChar()` function in the `System` unit).

<sup>1: I *suspect*, but can't confirm, that perhaps sometime between Delphi 1-4, directly assigning a `PWideChar` to an `String` was not supported yet, requiring an explicit function.  `AnsiString` was introduced in Delphi 2, so if `WideCharToString()` existed in Delphi 1 then it was likely to help faciliate the conversion of 16bit Unicode data to `String` when it was still an alias for `ShortString`.</sup>

When `UnicodeString` was introduced in Delphi 2009, the old ANSI-based RTL functions were updated (but not renamed) to support Unicode, including `WideCharToString()`, making it now merely copy the 16bit data as-is rather than convert it. And since a `PWideChar` can also be assigned directly to a `UnicodeString` (via the RTL's `System._UStrFromPWChar()` function), `WideCharToString()` is now completely redundant <sup>2</sup>.

<sup>2: unless Embarcadero/Idera ever decide to change the type of `String` again in the future, say to `UTF8String`.</sup>